# intelephense undefined constant/ vscode

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, code-completion, intelephense

code completion doesn't work (vscode on mac) when php open/ closing tags are on one line.
code completion works when three lines are used. please see screenshot.
how could this be resolved?
[php code completion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8mvj.jpg)
cheers
PJ

Answer (score 0):

What extension do you use? This one works fine for me (see screenshot). Also you should be able to activate it manually with CTRL+SPACE
[image]